# Is there a more accurate mousemove?

Tags: javascript, html

I was asking myself is there is a "more accurate mousemove" in JavaScript.
The normal event is fired when the mouse moves, but it's possible that it "jumps" over some pixels, so my question is if there's a way to detect *every* pixels that was crossed.

An application that could use this could be something like paint where you want to draw something (e.g. a stroke)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4g8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse does not cross every pixel, though.  Especially with touchscreens.

You can see this in Microsoft Paint.  If you drag the mouse back and forth while drawing, you'll see that it is just guessing and drawing lines in between the points the OS is sending it.

If you need to handle every pixel, then take the last pixel you saw, and the current pixel, and have your code find all of the pixels that fall on a line between the 2 points.

Comment: Thank you, that was my current approach aswell, instead of drawing points on the pixels the MouseMove-event game me I just draw a line between the current and the last point.